# How to set the default value of a Date in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to set the default value of a Date in an init extension, in Swift. I am not sure how to set it properly.

```
extension Habit {
    init(id: String, dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.startDate = dictionary["startDate"] as? Date
    }
}
```

I've tried unwrapping it with a null coalescent and an empty string, however, that does not work given a string is not of type Date.

What is the proper way to do this? Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: What do you want as the default date? I mean if the dictionary doesn't contain a value for "startDate".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set current date of device with giving `Date()` which gives you a current date of device

Comment: That works. I did `self.startDate = dictionary["startDate"] as? Date ?? Date()`. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect, cheers! can you mark answer is correct if it solve your problem? @Simbeul